# Ruby rand function in method

Tags: ruby, random

Using Ruby why can't I pass random variable here? I tried different combinations such as removing numbers.

```
money= rand(100)

def paycheck(money)
  "Lets make this amount, #{money} today"
end

puts paycheck("100")
puts paycheck("200")
puts paycheck("500")
```

Comment: Where are you trying to pass a random variable?

Comment: You may be confused about the meaning of `money` in different contexts. Inside the `paycheck` method, `money` is a new variable private to that method and has nothing to do with the `money` variable you declared outside the method. This is called shadowing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

```
money= rand(100)
puts paycheck(money)
```

When you define your method `paycheck(money)` - it is different variable `money` that the one on this line: `money = rand(100)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
def paycheck(limit)
  money = rand(limit.to_i)
  "Lets make this amount, #{money} today"
end

puts paycheck("100") #=> Lets make this amount, 14 today
puts paycheck("200") #=> Lets make this amount, 111 today
puts paycheck("500") #=> Lets make this amount, 119 today
```